# Python os.rename, remove and error catching

Tags: python, python-re

The script gets filenames from a directory, splits the file name and the extension. Characters ) and . are then removed from the file name and thus the file name is renamed. If an error occurs that indicates that a duplicate named file exists from that directory, it is handled by the exception block using os.remove. Printing the output before the try-except block produces desirable results but running the block produces no output as does printing after the block.

Why is the try-except block not functioning as intended?

```
import os
import re

os.chdir('E:\D\Music\Music V')

for f in os.listdir(): 
    fileName, fileExt =  os.path.splitext(f) 
    fileName = re.sub('[).]','',fileName)
    newName = '{}{}'.format(fileName, fileExt)

    #print(newName)

try:
    os.rename(f, newName)
except WindowsError:
    os.remove(newName)
    os.rename(f, newName)

    #print(newName)
```

Comment: You say you want to sub both closing paranthesis and literal dot. So I'd say you need a character class of `re.sub('[).],'',filename)`. Using a character class we don't need to escape these characters in the class using a backslash, hence we don't need to use raw string either.

Comment: Thank you @JvdV. The character class works. The try-except block remains disturbingly disfunctional.

Comment: I gave it a try with proper indentation, and it worked for me =) See below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this worked for me:

```
import os
import re

os.chdir('E:\D\Music\Music V')

for f in os.listdir(): 
    fileName, fileExt =  os.path.splitext(f) 
    fileName = re.sub('[).],'',filename)
    newName = '{}{}'.format(fileName, fileExt)

    #print(newName)

    try:
        os.rename(f, newName)
    except WindowsError:
        os.remove(newName)
        os.rename(f, newName)

        #print(newName)
```

Note that the extra indent for `try:`. Without it, it's not part of the same iteration in `for f`. Was it this simple? Hopefully =)

Comment: It actually is that simple thank you. The character class was a savior.